# Draw arrow with corners in tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, nodes

I want to draw a line with multiple corners/segments, i.e. instead of being straight, it looks more like a Z with an arrow on the end. The code for the first part of the line looks like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}
    \addplot graphics[xmin=0,xmax=5,ymin=0,ymax=5,] {Images/test}
        node (name2) at (300pt,102pt) {label} (name2.west) edge[-,color=white,very thick] (245pt,110pt);
    \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

How do I modify this so that the line continues on from the point (245pt,110pt) to (245pt,130pt) in the style `[-,color=white,very thick]`, then from (245pt,130pt) to (300pt,145pt) in the style `[-stealth,color=white,very thick]`?

Comment: Could you please provide a *Complete* [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3300/minimum-working-example-mwe)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I understand you want a simple line over four points with an arrow at the end, so you don't need the edge-tool. Without the plot (which I can't compile without a MWE), this should create what you want:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \node (name2) at (300pt,102pt) {label};
    \draw[-stealth,color=blue,very thick] (name2.west) -- (245pt,110pt) -- (245pt,130pt) -- (300pt,145pt);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your help. This is exactly what I was trying to do.

Comment: @Ulysses: Would be nice if you mark the answer as "Acceptet" in case it helped :)

Comment: I swear I did. Not sure why it didn't take.

Comment: No problem, don't care :D